# jQuery product filter using radio boxes and price slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, product

I need to be able to filter the products based on price (slider) and radio boxes. Looking at other posts here I've managed to get the basic functionality.
The problem is that my filter right now works with OR, and I need it to work with AND instead.

For example, I need to be able to get a product that is Brand1, TeamA and price range from 0 to 20. And this should be only one product, but I'm getting 7 products instead.

In the actual application I have 6 different attributes. Not sure if that matters, but just in case.

```
var $filters = $("input:radio[name='brand'],input:radio[name=team]").prop('checked', false); // start all unchecked

var $categoryContent = $('#CategoryContent li');
$filters.click(function() {
$categoryContent.hide();
$filters.filter(':checked').each(function(i, el) {
    $categoryContent.filter(':contains(' + el.value + ')').show();
});
});
```

Here is my working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/unGmL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the filter function needs to take into account the brand and team selected, not just the price. You're only filtering by price on slider events, and you're only filtering by category on click events. You need to do *both* of these things on *every* event.

I updated your fiddle to do both of these things: http://jsfiddle.net/unGmL/16/

Here's the updated showProducts:

```
function showProducts(minPrice, maxPrice) {
    $("#products li").hide().filter(function() {
      var $product = $(this),
          details = $product.html();
      // If min and max prices are specified, filter products by price
      if (min != null && max != null) {
        var price = parseInt($product.data("price"), 10);
        if (price < minPrice || price > maxPrice) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      var inputs = $("input:radio[name='brand']:checked,input:radio[name=team]:checked");
      // If team or brand are specified, filter products by
      // team/brand
      if (inputs.prop('checked')) {
        var found = true;
        inputs.each(function(index, cat) {
          var $input = $(this),
              cat = $input.val();
          // Both brand and team must match.
          // If brand and team are selected and one of them
          // is not matched, then product is filtered
          found = (details.indexOf(cat) >= 0) && found;
        });
        return found;
      }
      return true;
    }).show();
}
```

`showProducts` now looks at the checked radio boxes. If none of the radio boxes are checked, then brand and team filtering will not be applied. If a brand or team is desired, then each product is checked to contain the selected teams (if checked) AND the selected brand (if checked).

The variables `min` and `max` are relegated to the global closure so that price can be filtered in any event callback.

Comment: Thank you fruchtose, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the detailed explanation as well :)